# Incorporating a Search Bar with Vue.js to Trigger Actions in a Component

Tags: search, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-component, web-frontend

"Implementing a Search Bar in Vue.js for Front-End Data Filtering

I'm relatively new to Vue.js and I'm looking to integrate a search bar into my project. My goal is to perform data filtering on the front end. I'd like to know how to implement data filtering in the script section of the app bar on the default page. Additionally, I want to display the filtered query results in a component on the home page."

here is my component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <v-text-field
          label="Search"
          v-model="search"
          placeholder="topic, tag"
          outlined
          hide-details
          solo
          dense
          class="custom-text-field"
          :style="isAdmin === true ? 'display:none;' : ''"
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-col>
      <v-col>
        <v-btn
          icon
          :style="isAdmin === true ? 'display:none;' : ''"
          @click="performSearch"
        >
          <v-icon>mdi-magnify</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </div>
</template>
  
  <script>
export default {
  props: {
    isAdmin: Boolean,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      search: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    performSearch() {
      this.$emit('perform-search', this.search)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

here is my default page

```
<v-app-bar elevation="0" :clipped-left="clipped" fixed app>
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer" />
      <v-toolbar-title>{{ checkRole.title }}</v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
<search-bar :is-admin="localeRole === 'admin'" @perform-search="performSearch"></search-bar>
</v-app-bar>
<script>
import SearchBar from "~/components/search.vue"
export default {
  name: 'DefaultLayout',
components: { SearchBar },}
```

here is my home page

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row justify="center">
      <v-col cols="12" sm="8">
        <v-card elevation="0">
          <v-card elevation="1" class="mb-2">
            <v-tabs height="78" v-model="tab" grow color="primary">
              <v-tab v-for="(item, index) in localCheck" :key="index">
                <v-col no-gutters>
                  <center class="mt-0">
                    <v-img
                      class="mt-0"
                      height="32"
                      width="32" 
                      :src="pic(index)"
                    >
                    </v-img>
                  </center>
                  <h2 style="font-weight: normal !important">{{ item.tab }}</h2>
                </v-col>
              </v-tab>
            </v-tabs>
          </v-card>
     
          <div>
            <v-tabs-items v-model="tab">
              <v-tab-item v-for="(item, index) in localCheck" :key="index">
                <div>
                  <v-row>
                    <component
                      class="mx-4 pa-0"
                      :is="item.content"

                    ></component>
                  </v-row>
                </div>
              </v-tab-item>
            </v-tabs-items>
          </div>
        </v-card>
        <first :search-query="search"></first>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
<script>
import First from "~/components/Home/first_tab.vue";
import Second from "~/components/Home/second_tab.vue";
import Third from "~/components/Home/third_tab.vue";
import Search from "~/components/search.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    First,
    Second,
    Third,
    Search,
  },
```